# Why is the CSS cursor property not working with a custom URL?

Tags: html, css, mouse-cursor

CSS:

```css
#cursor {
  cursor: url(cursor.gif);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="cursor">
  <p>Hello world!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What browser have you been testing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property):

> zero or more URLs may be specified (comma-separated), which **must be followed** by one of the keywords defined in the CSS specification, such as `auto` or `pointer`.

Therefore you need to define a cursor value as [fallback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) for the `url()`.

For instance, using `auto`:

```css
#cursor {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor: url(//placehold.it/20), auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="cursor"></div>
```

Comment: It is working in latest version of Chrome on OS X :) (+1)

Comment: OP is trying to use .`gif` as cursor, isn't that the main point of this question?

Comment: @NenadVracar The main point was that it wasn't working at all. My answer showed that you need to add `auto`. Regardless of whether the image is a `png`/`gif`/jpg`, the issue is still the same.